# ImportError: No module named rpm

Tags: python, linux, centos, centos5

I installed python26 on my CentOS 5.3 machine using the following command. Now I have both python 2.4.3 and python 2.6 running on that machine.

```
yum install python26
```

When I run a python script with the following in the beginning of the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python26
```

I will get the following error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./centos-errata.py", line 70, in <module>
      import rpm
  ImportError: No module named rpm
```

But if I specify the following instead, it will not complain.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

How can I fix this error? Thanks.

Comment: Is the `rpm` module built and installed for Python 2.6?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that /usr/bin/python26 indeed exists.

do:

```
which python
```

Usually, symlink 'pyton' gets created that points to your most current executable.

Add in your code:

```
 import sys
 print sys.version
```

Then check if you have *rpm-python* installed.

Finally, it is possible that version or rpm does not match the version of Python you installed.
Be careful with CentOS and version of Python you install - later Python than 2.4 can break yum.
I think for your version, yum is built with Python 2.4.

Here are decent instructions on how to safely upgrade:
http://joshuakehn.com/2011/2/4/Upgrading-Python-on-CentOS.html